# Load jpg/png image in grub.cfg

Tags: boot, grub2

I have this grub.cfg that I use during the installation of the iso:

```
 set timeout=30

loadfont unicode

set menu_color_highlight=yellow/dark-gray
set menu_color_normal=black/light-gray
set color_normal=cyan/black


menuentry "bar Installation" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz   autoinstall   ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/nocloud/  ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "foo Installation" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz   autoinstall   ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/nocloud/  ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

how I can load jpg image or png image into this grub menu.
I tried insmod png and set background_image and it doesn't work - I get this error: "no video mode activated"

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, by adding this lines after "loadfont unicode":

```
insmod all_video 
terminal_output gfxterm 
insmod jpeg
```